# Using IMAP to fetch emails in php

Tags: php, imap

I am using Imap function to fetch the emails through yahoo mail.
Then i set the flag on each email because when in future i call the imap search i will not get the emails that are already fetched.This is how i get the emails.

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,"UNFLAGGED");
```

Then i apply the flag using the code :

```
foreach($emails as $email_number) {
       imap_setflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Flagged \\Seen", ST_UID);
```

But when i call the `imap_search($inbox,"UNFLAGGED");` i get the same emails.
The emails which are already been flagged should not fetch when i call the imap_search second time.

I Also tried `imap_search($inbox,"unflagged")` and `imap_search($inbox,"Unflagged")` and `imap_search($inbox,"UnFlagged")` but still all emails are fetched.

I tried `imap_search($inbox,"UNSEEN")` it is useful in case when the email is not read manually by user (Logging in yahoo mail and then read).
In my case i need all the emails which are not "Flagged" by me using Imap.

Need help on this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching message sequence numbers, but setting flags on UIDs.  Pick one or the other.  I suggest *always* using UIDs.  Have you tried adding SE_UID to search:

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox, "UNFLAGGED", SE_UID);
```